# How to close a userform and open another in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have one userform in the workbook "main.xlsm" that opens upon opening the workbook, on this userform i have one button that opens another workbook "test1.xlsm". In the "test1.xlsm" workbook i have a userform that opens upon opening the workbook, on this userform i have one button that closes this workbook and saves it. The idea was that after closing the userform from "test1.xlsm" i should get back to the userfom from "main.xlsm", but on the line  `Workbooks("test1.xlsm").Close` it closes all the opened userforms

this is the code for the button from the userform in "main.xlsm" :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Workbooks.Open ("D:\test1.xlsm")
End Sub
```

this is the code for the button from the userform in "main.xlsm" :

```
Private Sub SaveButton1_Click()
    Workbooks("D:\test1.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking this question on an [excel](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1213863-how-do-i-open-a-userfom-on-closing-another-userform.html) forum i got the suggestion to change the `ShowModal` property for each form to `ShowModal FALSE`. So i added the this argument to my  code in `ThisWorkbook`:

```
  UserForm1.Show vbModeless
```

in both userforms and it worked.